# OSM Tools Plugin is broken for QGIS 2.8.6-Wien

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, linux-mint, osmtools

When installing OSM Tools for QGIS Wien 2.8.6 I get an error:

> the plugin is broken python said no module named YAML.

YAML is on my Linux Mint box 18 and I can't find documentation with Google or on the developer website.

Any insights or answers?

Comment: I had similar issues installing this plugin using QGIS 2. Have you tried upgrading to QGIS 3? It works for me in Qgis3.

Comment: Why so old QGIS? Why not 2.18.x Las Palmas LTR? You can probably use the Debian repo https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

Comment: Because 3 is not a mature branch and does not have the functionlity I'm used to. Has nothing to do with my question BTW.